# Multiplying a certain element in a dataframe, given that certain element is the same as the filename of a CSV file in R

Tags: r, dplyr, bigdata

I am trying to solve big data problems and this involves 2 different CSV files.
If the filename of CSV1 matches a certain element in CSV2, I will multiply each element of CSV1 to that certain element of CSV2. I am using R by the way.

Let's take these as data samples:

CSV1 filename is: 318

```
01/01/2005 00:00        0.1
01/01/2005 01:00        0.4
01/01/2005 02:00        0.5
```

CSV2:

```
hey 318 0.08
sol 497 0.22
mat 498 0.06
```

thus 0.1. 0.4 and 0.5 of CSV1 must be multiplied by 0.08

Comment: are you doing this for many csv* files? why don't you add the file name (318) as a column to csv1, merge csv2 to csv1 using the second column as the id (keeping only the last column of csv2), and multiple the two columns together

Comment: unfortunately, yes. I have to do this to a thousand of files with thousands of rows each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do get all the filenames for which you want to apply this using `list.files`, loop over each filename, read it, `match` it with `csv2` dataframe and get corresponding value to multiply.

```
filenames <- list.files('path/of/files', full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$")

list_df <- lapply(filenames, function(x) transform(read.csv(x, header = FALSE), 
             V3 = V3 * csv2$V3[match(
                  tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)), csv2$V2)]))
```

This will return you updated list of dataframes that can be accessed like `list_df[[1]]`, `list_df[[2]]` etc.

where `csv2` is

```
csv2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("hey", 
"mat", "sol"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(318L, 497L, 498L), V3 = c(0.08, 
0.22, 0.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: hi sir,  V3 = V3 * csv2$V3[match(
                  tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)), csv2$V2)])), did it correspond to e.g. 0.1. 0.4 and 0.5 of CSV1  multiplied to 0.08?

Comment: yes, so I am assuming `csv1$V3` is 0.1. 0.4 and 0.5, `csv2$V2` is 318, 497 and 498 and `csv2$V3` is 0.08, 0.22 and 0.06. If the column names are called something else please adjust accordingly.

Comment: i am still trying to figure out as I cannot see the two elements being multiplied in my work. i wanted to extract the two dataframes in csv2 but i got error saying the two dfs have different number of rows.

Comment: sir, what if CSV2 is not structured to be a list (just like what was shown above). I actually wanted it to be read in R as another data frame (by letting R read the csv2 file thru read.csv command).

Comment: @karate `csv2` shared above is just for demonstration purposes. If you have data in csv do `csv2 <- read.csv('csv2.csv')` and use that.